# booleans().example() always returns True

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

To reproduce:

```py
In [1]: from hypothesis import strategies as st

In [2]: bool_st = st.booleans()

In [3]: all(bool_st.example() for _ in range(1000))
Out[3]: True
```

Why does `st.booleans().example()` always return `True`?  My understanding is that the `example` method should return examples of what could be output by a strategy and does so somewhat at random.

Relatedly, `st.sampled_from(...)` seems to never return the first item in the iterable:

```py
In [1]: from hypothesis import strategies as st

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: samp_st = st.sampled_from(list(range(10)))

In [4]: examples = [samp_st.example() for _ in range(1000)]

In [5]: cnt = Counter(examples)

In [6]: cnt.most_common()
Out[6]: [(1, 512), (2, 282), (3, 119), (4, 55), (5, 22), (6, 5), (7, 4), (8, 1)]
```

So what's going on here?

I'm aware that the `example` method documentation says the method "shouldn't be taken too seriously" (see [here](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/31a181fb7c5ce4227d4475f667a776ce86cd412c/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/searchstrategy/strategies.py#L258-L266)).  But this offers very little in the way of explanation and it would be nice to get more insight into why this is happening.

Comment: You might want to explain the context of your question and code snippet.

Comment: I don't know what `st.booleans().example()` is, but [being considered true is the default for most objects.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: My first assumption was "st.booleans() holds a state and we should not recreate it each time, save it to a variable", but it is wrong, because, e.g. `[st.integers().example() for _ in range(20)]` produces different numbers. Another assumption that `[st.booleans().example() for _ in range(20)]` is similar to `[bool(st.integers().example()) for _ in range(20)]` and therefore it is almost always `True`, though I cannot neither prove nor disprove this. (these are only thoughts, I did not use `hypothesis` before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: the `.example()` method avoids showing the simplest possible example from a strategy, because that example is usually trivial.  Admittedly this is less useful for `st.booleans().example()`, but that's why!

For your comments, `lists(...).example()` keeps producing the empty list due to a limitation in our uniqueness detection - see issues 1864, 1982, and PR 1961 for more details; we'll fix it as soon as we have a good way to do so.

[You can find the code for `.example()` here.](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/ca883ddd81280e34867d135d946398044b679930/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/searchstrategy/strategies.py#L290-L318)

Comment: Then what about `st.lists(st.booleans()).example()`?  That usually returns `[]` which is the simplest possible example.

Comment: Also, is there a particular area of code in the hypothesis library that would make it clear that this is the explanation for this behavior?  I tried to poke around and identify something like that previously but couldn't really find my way.

Comment: Ah, great I see it.  My eyes just didn't pick that section out when I skimmed over it previously.